# Matching a sequence of two integers into an `std::pair<int, int>`

Tags: c++, c++14, boost-fusion, boost-spirit-x3

I'm trying to use [Boost.Sprit x3](http://ciere.com/cppnow15/x3_docs/) to match a sequence of two integers into an `std::pair<int, int>`. Judging by the documentation, the following code should compile:

---

```
#include <string>
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::spirit::x3;

    std::string input("1 2");
    std::pair<int, int> result;
    parse(input.begin(), input.end(), int_ >> int_, result);
}
```

[*melpon.org link*](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/MbbVoWEugblRZibH)

---

However, it only matches the first integer. If I change `std::pair<int, int> result;` to `int result;` and then print `result`, I get `1` as my output.

Why is that happening? Isn't `int_ >> int_` the correct way of defining a parser that matches *(and sets as attributes)* two integers?

Comment: It looks like you need to include the relevant Boost.Fusion header that adapts `std::pair`.

Comment: @T.C.: yes, that solved the problem. Thanks! Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, @T.C. 's comment of including `<boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>` is only enough to silence the compiler, not to correctly parse your string. I also had to change the `x3::parse()` for a `x3::phrase_parse()` that skips over whitespace:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/config/warning_disable.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted/std_pair.hpp>

int main()
{
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    std::string input("1 2");
    std::pair<int, int> result;
    auto ok = x3::phrase_parse(input.begin(), input.end(), x3::int_ >> x3::int_, x3::space, result);
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << ok << ": ";
    std::cout << result.first << ", " << result.second;
}
```

[**Live Example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ab590a9ee52ecd89)

Note that I also replaced your `using namespace boost::spirit::x3` with a namespace alias `x3`. This will keep the readability but will prevent from dumping the huge of amount of Boost.Spirit symbols into your code.